# Reduce dimension of a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

I have the dataframe, contains three columns. I want to reduce the dimensions of the dataframe.

```
  data = [[1, 876, 0.98],[1, 888, 0.58],[1, 976, 0.48],[1, 648, 0.98],[2, 765, 0.28], [2, 986, 0.28], [2, 765, 1.0], [2, 876, 0.45]]
    sample = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1','col2', 'col3'])
   col1  col2  col3
0     1   876  0.98
1     1   888  0.58
2     1   976  0.48
3     1   648  0.98
4     2   765  0.28
5     2   986  0.28
6     2   765  1.00
7     2   876  0.45
```

I want below as the desired output based on condition:
1. For every value in col1, there should be one row and col 4 should be list of tuples(col2, col3)
2. col4 should have only top two tuples based on values in col3. For example in sample dataframe,in col2 765 has occurred two times,final dataframe should take the one which has the highest value in col3 and second highest

```
data = [[1, [(876, 0.98),(648, 0.98)]],[2, [(876, 0.45), (765, 1.0)]]]
desired_output = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1', 'col2'])

   col1                        col4
0     1  [(876, 0.98), (648, 0.98)]
1     2   [(876, 0.45), (765, 1.0)]
```

I want to store in a list of tuple so that I can use this for some other purpose.This is just a part of solving bigger problem.

Comment: Don't store lists in a DataFrame.  Feel free to pivot and create new columns, but don't store the output like this

Comment: `sample.sort_values('col3').groupby('col1').tail(2)` , this is the right format for this type of question

Comment: `sample.sort_values('col3').groupby('col1').tail(2).sort_values('col1')` would order it as he wants it too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FWIW

```
sample = sample.sort_values(['col1', 'col3'], ascending=[True, False])
sample.groupby('col1')[['col2', 'col3']].apply(
    lambda d: [*d.head(2).itertuples(index=False)]
).reset_index(name='col4')

   col1                        col4
0     1  [(876, 0.98), (648, 0.98)]
1     2   [(765, 1.0), (876, 0.45)]
```

---

Those will be named tuples.  You can avoid that with `name=None`

```
sample = sample.sort_values(['col1', 'col3'], ascending=[True, False])
sample.groupby('col1')[['col2', 'col3']].apply(
    lambda d: [*d.head(2).itertuples(index=False, name=None)]
).reset_index(name='col4')
```

Comment: WHen I am runnign the above code in python console it shows me the desired output but When I m storing it as csv, it is store in the below format:    
   `       col1    col2
0        1        [Pandas(col2=876,col3=0.98), Pandas(col2=648, col3=0.98)]
1        2         [Pandas(col2=765,col3=1.00), Pandas(col2=876, col3=0.45)]`